# Disable background scrolling when mat dialog is open

Tags: angular, angular-material

Opening a dialog using MatDialog in Angular Material doesn't prevent background content from scrolling

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

You can add this after opening the dialog:

```js
document.body.classList.add("cdk-global-scrollblock");
```

And this after closing the dialog:

```js
document.body.classList.remove("cdk-global-scrollblock");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i'm using gsap animation for parallax scroll to content.
And opening the mat-dialog was causing the same issue.
However, the class "cdk-global-scrollblock" was on html tag

```html
<html class="cdk-global-scrollblock" style="...">...</html>
```

I had to remove the scrollblock on the html tag after opening the mat-dialog

```js
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(WorkDialogCardComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: this.item.data,
});

// Remove the scrollblock added by mat-dialog
document.documentElement.classList.remove("cdk-global-scrollblock");
```